# Extract individual white parts of binarized image

Tags: image-processing

Suppose we have an image, like so:

[image]

and I managed to create its MorphologicalGraph by using

```
p1 = Binarize[*the image*];
p2 = Thinning[Pruning[Thinning[DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[DeleteSmallComponents[p1, 300]], 300]]]]
MorphologicalGraph[p2]
```

Which gave the result of

[image: Graph]

If we overlay the two, we can see how most of it lines up. Is there a way to extract the white parts in the image individually? I'm thinking of using `MorphologicalGraph` to extract the enclosed spaces, but any method / tip that can achieve extracting the white parts individually is perfect and greatly appreciated.

For example, each of those numbered is a part that is to be extracted. [image: example]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One approach is to use:

```
MorphologicalComponents[Erosion[img, 1]] // Colorize
```

[image]

Then you can access the individual colored sections using ComponentMeasurements. For example:

```
ComponentMeasurements[comp // Colorize, {"Image", "Count", "Mean"}, All, "Dataset"]
```

gives a long list of all the segments and how large they are. You can sort them by many different properties. Here is a piece of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for `MorphologicalComponents[*the image*]`.  This function groups connected areas of white pixels and assigns them a single integer.  For example;

```
mc = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[*the image*]]
```

Then

```
Graphics[Flatten@
  Table[Style[Text[mc[[i, j]], {i, j}], 8], {i, 300, 350}, {j, 300, 
    350}], ImageSize -> 8 72]
```

gives the following subset of the `mc` data

[image]

As you can see, each cluster of white pixels now has a unique number, such as 81 in the case of the upper left corner of this graphic.  The 0s correspond to the black areas.  You can use `SelectComponents[mc, -criteria-]` to search for large, small, round, etc features.  Below I choose the 10 largest.

```
Colorize@SelectComponents[mc, "Area", -10]
```

[image]

To see which integers are assigned to which cluster of white pixels, use the following;

```
centroids = ComponentMeasurements[mc, "Centroid"];
```

where `centroids[[1]]` gives `1 -> {674.491, 672.}`

```
Show[
 Colorize@mc, 
  Graphics[ {White,
   Table[ Text[centroids[[i, 1]], centroids[[i, 2]]], {i, Length@centroids}]}]
]
```

[image]